# Does Hearthstone allow games with no time limits between rounds?

Tags: hearthstone

I'd like to play games of Hearthstone with some friends while at work, but in a more casual style where 10-15 minutes may pass between our plays. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this feature is currently only available through Solo Adventures.  Unfortunately, at the moment there's no option for unlimited turn timers when dueling other players.